# XSD help needed

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using Eclipse Kepler with the Saxon plug-in. Using the following Input XML and the following XSL.  Any Ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

My Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="weathertbos.xsl" ?>
<GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
    <GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
        <Success>true</Success>
        <ResponseText>City Found</ResponseText>
        <State>FL</State>
        <City>Clearwater</City>
        <WeatherStationCity>Clearwater</WeatherStationCity>
        <WeatherID>14</WeatherID>
        <Description>Cloudy</Description>
        <Temperature>73</Temperature>
        <RelativeHumidity>90</RelativeHumidity>
        <Wind>NE10</Wind>
        <Pressure>30.07R</Pressure>
        <Visibility />
        <WindChill />
        <Remarks />
    </GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
</GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse>
```

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:weat="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv max">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
            <max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
                <max:WEATHER action="AddChange">
                    <max:SUCCESS>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Success" />
                    </max:SUCCESS>
                    <max:RESPONSETEXT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ResponseText" />
                    </max:RESPONSETEXT>
                    <max:STATE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="State" />
                    </max:STATE>
                    <max:CITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="City" />
                    </max:CITY>
                    <max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="WeatherStationCity" />
                    </max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY>
                    <max:WEATHERID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="WeatherID" />
                    </max:WEATHERID>
                    <max:DESCRIPTION>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Description" />
                    </max:DESCRIPTION>
                    <max:TEMPERATURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Temperature" />
                    </max:TEMPERATURE>
                    <max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="RelativeHumidity" />
                    </max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY>
                    <max:WIND>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Wind" />
                    </max:WIND>
                    <max:PRESSURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Pressure" />
                    </max:PRESSURE>
                    <max:VISIBILITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Visibility" />
                    </max:VISIBILITY>
                    <max:WINDCHILL>
                        <xsl:value-of select="WindChill" />
                    </max:WINDCHILL>
                    <max:REMARKS>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Remarks" />
                    </max:REMARKS>
                </max:WEATHER>
            </max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
        </max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS xmlns:weat="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
    <max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
        <max:WEATHER action="AddChange">
            <max:SUCCESS />
            <max:RESPONSETEXT />
            <max:STATE />
            <max:CITY />
            <max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY />
            <max:WEATHERID />
            <max:DESCRIPTION />
            <max:TEMPERATURE />
            <max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY />
            <max:WIND />
            <max:PRESSURE />
            <max:VISIBILITY />
            <max:WINDCHILL />
            <max:REMARKS />
        </max:WEATHER>
    </max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
</max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS xmlns:weat="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
    <max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
        <max:WEATHER action="AddChange">
            <max:SUCCESS>true</max:SUCCESS>
            <max:RESPONSETEXT>City Found</max:RESPONSETEXT>
            <max:STATE>FL</max:STATE>
            <max:CITY>Clearwater</max:CITY>
            <max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY>Clearwater</max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY>
            <max:WEATHERID>14</max:WEATHERID>
            <max:DESCRIPTION>Cloudy</max:DESCRIPTION>
            <max:TEMPERATURE>73</max:TEMPERATURE>
            <max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY>90</max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY>
            <max:WIND>NE10</max:WIND>
            <max:PRESSURE>30.07R</max:PRESSURE>
            <max:VISIBILITY />
            <max:WINDCHILL />
            <max:REMARKS />
        </max:WEATHER>
    </max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
</max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS>
```

I have tried several options such as:

```
<max:SUCCESS>
    <xsl:value-of select="/GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse/GetCityWeatherByZIPResult/Success"/>
</max:SUCCESS>
```

And using :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:weat="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/" exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv max">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="GetCityWeatherByZIPResult" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="GetCityWeatherByZIPResult">
        <max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
            <max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
                <max:WEATHER action="AddChange">
                    <max:SUCCESS>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Success" />
                    </max:SUCCESS>
                    <max:RESPONSETEXT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ResponseText" />
                    </max:RESPONSETEXT>
                    <max:STATE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="State" />
                    </max:STATE>
                    <max:CITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="City" />
                    </max:CITY>
                    <max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="WeatherStationCity" />
                    </max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY>
                    <max:WEATHERID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="WeatherID" />
                    </max:WEATHERID>
                    <max:DESCRIPTION>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Description" />
                    </max:DESCRIPTION>
                    <max:TEMPERATURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Temperature" />
                    </max:TEMPERATURE>
                    <max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="RelativeHumidity" />
                    </max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY>
                    <max:WIND>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Wind" />
                    </max:WIND>
                    <max:PRESSURE>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Pressure" />
                    </max:PRESSURE>
                    <max:VISIBILITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Visibility" />
                    </max:VISIBILITY>
                    <max:WINDCHILL>
                        <xsl:value-of select="WindChill" />
                    </max:WINDCHILL>
                    <max:REMARKS>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Remarks" />
                    </max:REMARKS>
                </max:WEATHER>
            </max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
        </max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The number 1 XSLT mistake reported on this forum: you're ignoring the fact that the elements are in a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **namespace** issue; the tag `GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse` is assigned the namespace uri *http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/*, you need to match your tags with the prefix `weat` that has been declared on the root of your stylesheet.

You need to modify your stylesheet that wa, if I take the last attempt you posted (please note your stylesheet has been abridged to keep the answer as brief as possible, full XSL is [here](http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2CV)):

```
<xsl:template match="weat:GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="weat:GetCityWeatherByZIPResult" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="weat:GetCityWeatherByZIPResult">
    <max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
        <max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
            <max:WEATHER action="AddChange">
                <max:SUCCESS>
                    <xsl:value-of select="weat:Success" />
                </max:SUCCESS>
                <max:RESPONSETEXT>
                    <xsl:value-of select="weat:ResponseText" />
                </max:RESPONSETEXT>
                <!-- and so on ... -->
            </max:WEATHER>
        </max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
    </max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS>
</xsl:template>
```

This is my output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS xmlns:weat="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"
                      xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
   <max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
      <max:WEATHER action="AddChange">
         <max:SUCCESS>true</max:SUCCESS>
         <max:RESPONSETEXT>City Found</max:RESPONSETEXT>
         <max:STATE>FL</max:STATE>
         <max:CITY>Clearwater</max:CITY>
         <max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY>Clearwater</max:WEATHERSTATIONCITY>
         <max:WEATHERID>14</max:WEATHERID>
         <max:DESCRIPTION>Cloudy</max:DESCRIPTION>
         <max:TEMPERATURE>73</max:TEMPERATURE>
         <max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY>90</max:RELATIVEHUMIDITY>
         <max:WIND>NE10</max:WIND>
         <max:PRESSURE>30.07R</max:PRESSURE>
         <max:VISIBILITY/>
         <max:WINDCHILL/>
         <max:REMARKS/>
      </max:WEATHER>
   </max:WEATHERRSPOSSet>
</max:SyncWEATHERRSPOS>
```

Comment: You're welcome. But I believe it is not an issue regarding Eclipse -- as I mentioned, it is related to namespaces management in your XML and in XPath.